# Ticks per second

Tags: mql5

I would like to calculate the number of ticks (or alternatively the price change) per second. Unfortunately MQL5's [ENUM_TIMEFRAMES](https://www.mql5.com/de/docs/constants/chartconstants/enum_timeframes) only goes down to 1 min. [This indicator](https://www.mql5.com/en/market/product/48#description) proves it's possible, though, but how?  Maybe by means of the [OnTimer event](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis/function/events#ontimer)?

Many thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` time is number of seconds since the new computer era. if you call `TimeCurrent()` that returns `datetime`, it will give you integer. if you call it again in 0.1 second, you will receive same integer (or same+1). The indicator may count number of ticks in OnCalculate() and comparing with old time.
something like this:

```
datetime lastTime;
int ticksLastSecond;
OnCalculate(***){
   if(TimeCurrent()>lastTime){
      lastTime=TimeCurrent();ticksLastSecond=1;
   }else{ticksLastSecond++;}
}
```

if necessary, add `ticksLastSecond` in an array to average over last minute or any other period

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. Would you still help me with the average/with creating a rolling array?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608058/rolling-static-array

Comment: sure, no problem