# Rolling (static) array?

Tags: mql5

Based on [ticks per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600384/ticks-per-second) (`ticksLastSecond`), I would now like to calculate the *average* ticks per second over the last minute. For this, I would need a ***rolling*** array with size = 60 I assume, each second pushing the array elements forward by the newest `ticksLastSecond` value (preferrably at the *beginning (0)* of the array) and the oldest one out. How could this be achieved?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use arrays, keeping in mind the following: if you need average of 60 (x) values, your array could be of size 60(which is very impractical: you will need to copy elements 1 to 59 into 0 to 58 each second) or 120(copying once per minute) more. So, 120 is preferred I think, more is of no need.

```
input int size = 60;
int array[];
ArraySize(array,2*size);
int cursor=0; //- shows position of the last element

void add(const int element){
   if(cursor>=2*size-1)resize();
   array[cursor++]=element;
}
void resize(){
   ArrayCopy(array,array,0,size);
   cursor=size;
}
//for array average: iMAOnArray() or manually:
double getAvg(){
   if(cursor+1<size)return 0;
   double sum=0;
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      sum+=array[cursor-1-i];
   }
   return(sum/cursor);
}
```

also possible to keep computed value of average and then add last, subtract first-this will speed up even more, think in case of backtesting.
This all might be better to put in a structure.

Same but easier is use of `CArrayInt` or `CArrayObj` - in such case you do not worry about size, use methods `Add()` and `DeleteRange(0,size-1)`, for looping :
`Total() and`At(i);

Another approach is to use a linked list in mql5, with easy access to first and last element. It is already implemented so try `CLinkedList<T> : public ICollection`
[here](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/generic/clinkedlist)

Comment: Thank you very much again, Daniel! You declared the add() function and probably still wanted to call it, too? What I don‘t fully understand: you append each new tick sum per second to the end of the array and then overwrite by ArrayCopy (great idea to use this function) the newer values with the older ones (starting at the element @ [size]), and of that I‘m not sure since the last function parameter of ArrayCopy has been omitted and therefore it defaults to the whole array? Anyway, many thanks, your answers helped me a lot!

Comment: resize gets rid of half of the array when it becomes too large (double of the length that definitely is twice more of what you need)

Comment: Hi, I just tested your code but it seems that ArrayCopy(array,array,0,size); doesn't work. I like the idea very much, but are you sure an array can be copied into itself?

Comment: yes, array can be copied into itself. show the problem by editing your post and we will see what might be the problem

Comment: Yes, you are right, many thanks! I just had to initiate the whole array to 0 first, otherwise strange (=huge!) numbers appeared and distorted the average! But please tell me: why do I have to write "double div = 5.0/3;" instead of "double div = 5/3;" just in order to get the correct result (1.66666) instead of 1???

Comment: 5 and 3 are integers, 5.0 is double. if you divide integer by integer, you will receive integer - in c++ and most other langs, so 1.667 would be converted into integer = 1. if one of the elements if double then result is double also

Comment: Hi Daniel! I hope it's not a silly question, but I would like to program a stop loss as an object (a function would also do) that increments no matter what at each interval, driven by a multiplier. The multiplier should start at 1 and increment by 1 at each interval, no problem so far. However, how do I reset it to 1 after the SL has been hit (the SL-object won't be called when the SL is hit)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...if it was a function I could write "multiplier = 1;" (given that "multiplier" is a global variable) between order execution and SL-function, right, but in an object "multiplier" would have to be declared as the object's own (local) variable, wouldn't it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: (the SL-object isn't placed in the main program, but in an include file if that matters)

Comment: hi. this doesnt seem to be related so why you havent accepted the answer?

Comment: about multiplier: declare a global variable (not a global variable of clients' terminal, but just a global variable) and then have a list of open trades (or just one, then keep OrderTicket() in memory, and check each tick, if order doesnt exist then check if closed by stoploss or not, if by stoploss then reset multiplier to zero (or one) and despite that clear last ticket number

Comment: Hello! No, it‘s not related. I liked the idea of ArrayCopy() a lot but had to implement the rest somehow differently to work for me, so I upvoted it. Anyway, I accepted it now, too, that makes 25 points in total, right? Thanks for all your answers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that using lists is more efficient.

MQL5 provides a series of mechanisms to work with lists.
For instance, what I would do is to declare a CList and create a class for the items of the list with the necessary attributes. In your case the time of the tick.

```
#include <Arrays\List.mqh>
#include <Object.mqh>

int storedItems = 60;
CList *listTicks = new CList;

class listItem : public CObject {
    public:
        listItem(double n){value=n;};
        double getValue(){return value;};
    private:
        double value;
};
```

Then, in the `OnTick` function, I'd check if the list is full to delete the head item. Finally, I'd insert the new item at the end of the list:

```
if(listTicks.Total() == storedTicks)
    listTicks.Delete(0);
listTicks.Add(new listItem(tick_time));
```

Instead of copying, deleting, inserting... items in an array, a list only modifies the pointer to the previous and the next item. So it's much more computationally efficient.